# PHP not show print date class

Tags: php

I have this class for convert date to arabic date and show/print date in arabic.

PHP Arabic class [HERE](http://madenade.besaba.com/class.txt):

for print arabic date:

```
<?PHP $arabicdate = new ArabicTools;
echo $arabicdate->arabicDate('Y',1445299200);
?>
```

But this code print this output: `Y`

How do can i fix this problem?!

[DEMO](http://madenade.besaba.com/form.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a global check and I believe it's related to what you do at the end in the `arabicDate($format, $timestamp)`:

```
if ($type == "ah:") $date = $format . " AH";
  else $date = $format;
```

So what you pass as a parameter to that function is returned by:

```
if ($use_span) return '<span dir="rtl" lang="ar-sa">' . $date . '</span>';
  else return $date;
```

Therefore you get the `Y` because it never enters the code block that you have inside `if ($type == 'hj:' || $type == "ah:")` (since `$type = substr($format, 0, 3)` and `$format` is just `Y`), so the `$format` is never changed besides the `$format = trim($format)` at the beginning.

Try instead `echo $arabicdate->arabicDate('hj:',1445299200);` (or using `'ah:'`) and you may get a more interesting result...

Comment: `echo $arabicdate->arabicDate('hj',1445299200);` reslut is : `hj`

Comment: Sure, i change `hj` or `ah` to `l: d / F / Y` but result is `l: d / F / Y`. i think my problem is : `$arabicdate->arabicDate('Y',1445299200);` this method

Comment: @Perspolis You are only accepting 2 types of `$format` (`'hj:'` or `'ah:'`) because of that condition (`if ($type == 'hj:' || $type == "ah:")`). If you change this condition to accept others like `if ($type == 'Y' || $type == "F" || $type == "d")`, it will enter that block. The `list(...) = explode(...)` will divide the `timestamp` into variables that are used inside that if block.

Comment: @Perspolis Thanks :)  Next time you can also use this website ([ideone.com](http://ideone.com/W7qR8m)) to place your PHP code: it will be compiled and become syntax colored!